# Comparing compass bearings

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have several compass bearings:

bTrue = 190°
b1 = 250°
b2 = 100°
b3 = 170°
b4 = 90°

I want to compare b1 - b4 and find out how close they are to bTrue. So bTrue is 100%. How much percent is then b1, b2, b3, and b4? 360°-180° would be 0%.

---

The use case is that have GPS locations with bearings that I am trying to match to road segments, where I also know the bearing. Besides the distance to the road I also want to consider bearing. b1 - b4 are the bearings of the road and bTrue is the bearing of the GPS point.

Comment: As the comments in @AlexR's answers state, this seems to be a silly problem. Another not-yet-stated reason for the silliness is that the reference direction, north, is arbitrary. Measuring the angles from another reference direction, such as east, would give a different percent error. Where did this problem come from?

Comment: @RoryDaulton Note the suggested translation invariant error does not show this oddity.

Comment: @RoryDaulton, I'm not an expert in all areas of human endeavor, with that disclaimer, I'm not aware of any use of bearing where the reference heading is not north. Whether local magnetic or true north is used for the reference can sometimes be an issue, but that's very different from east being the reference heading, which truly would be silly.

Comment: @ToddWilcox: "East" (to the right) is the reference direction in trigonometry as well in some computer graphics. We also have the issue of measuring the angle clockwise or counterclockwise.

Comment: Maybe this is a cultural thing, since I've never heard the direction of the positive $x$-axis referred to as "East", nor heard any angle reference outside of a navigational context referred to as a "bearing" or a "heading".

Comment: I added some more context that might help understanding the question.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking for the relative error:
$$e_{\text{rel}} = \frac{|x-\hat x|}{|x|} = \frac{60^\circ}{190^\circ} \approx 0.3158 = 31.58\% $$

Note that the relative error is not translation invariant and doesn't provide a good measure for error in this case. An absolute error would be more reasonable:

$$e_{\text{abs}} = |x-\hat x| = 60^\circ$$
Also note that the error measure should identify $0^\circ = 360^\circ$ so an even better measure would be given by

$$e = \min(|x-\hat x| \!\mod 360^\circ, 360^\circ - |x-\hat x| \!\mod 360^\circ)$$
This is fully translation invariant (adding any 'normal bearing' to all measurements doesn't change the error).

The latter will give $e=3^\circ$ for your second example, reflecting that the compass needle with bearing $2^\circ$ is in fact much closer to $359^\circ$ than $250^\circ$ is to $190^\circ$.

Comment: What about the case of b1 = 359° and b2 = 2°? Then the error is 178.5, isn't it?

Comment: No, it will be $<100\%$ but close to $100\%$. The error $e_{\text{rel}}$ says that
$$x\cdot (1-e_{\text{rel}}) \le \hat x \le x \cdot (1+e_{\text{rel}})$$

Comment: Percentage error doesn't even make sense for compass bearings. Your formula says that a 30 degree error in a bearing of 90 is relatively larger than a 30 degree error in a bearing of 100. But that's nonsense.

Comment: @MJD About the sense of a relative error in bearings, I totally agree with you. The question however precisely asked for this.

Comment: @MJD I've taken the time to elaborate a little bit an suggest a better error measure. Thanks for your criticism :)

Comment: Most likely some kind of concept of relative error is defined elsewhere in the work from which the problem in question came. Or at least we would hope so. That being said, there is some sense in defining 100% relative error in a bearing as being a bearing that is $180^\circ$ different from the desired bearing.

Comment: @ToddWilcox That would essentially be a re-scaled version of my proposed error, but only the OP will be able to tell us.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding the answer on GIS Stackexchange.

The simple calculation of `abs(1 - abs(bTrue - bx)/180)` does the trick.

Comment: This can't be a correct percentage because it may be negative. cf.
$$1- \frac{|359^\circ - 2^\circ|}{180} = 1 - \frac{357}{180} \approx -0.983$$
Something yielding a correct percentage value similar to your equation is the $e$ from my answer, when divided by $180$. The same bearings give an $e$ of $3^\circ$ and thus a percentage error of $\frac3{180} \approx 0.0167 = 1.67\%$